# OBS Shut Down When Trying to Run It

Tags: obs-studio

I am using Kubuntu 14.04 and tried running OBS Studio in the terminal and I have ffmpeg installed but when I typed "obs" in terminal, it came up with a license agreement and I pushed 'I Agree' but once I did that it just shut down and came up with,

```
error: Failed to create OpenGL context.
error: Failed to create context!
*** Error in `obs': double free or corruption (out): 0x0000000001a30080 ***
Aborted (core dumped)"
```

Could someone please help? Thanks!

Comment: I also use OBS but haven't updated in awhile, did you add the PPA, I think the PPA is much further up to date than the raw binaries.

Comment: Yeah I added the PPA

Comment: Could you add some basic details, like what version of Ubuntu you're on and have you installed `ffmpeg`?

Comment: Sure! Yeah I'll do that

Comment: What's the output of `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` ? It may be that the OpenGL Version or Features OBS requires aren't compatible with your graphics card.

Comment: I'm not sure how to find the output. Could you tell me?

Comment: Just type it into a terminal and give us what it shows.

Comment: what type of graphics card do you have?

Answer (score 1):

As per the discussion at the OBS Project page:

https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/opengl-outstanding-bug-in-ubuntu-14-04.25244/

Basically what this all boils down to is that OBS makes use of features in OpenGL 3.2 and above.  This is most likely specifically related to screen capture, and this is specific to the linux platform.  They use directx in windows.

Now you can check and see if you currently support OpenGL 3.2 with this command:

```
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL core"
```

If you are supporting a lower value than OpenGL 3.2, you'll bomb out with the above error message.  Which especially sucks if you weren't even planning on doing a screen capture =P

Possible remedies are switching between open source and proprietary drivers.  some have better GL support than others depending on the card.